# How to make glossaries and nomenclature work together?

Tags: glossaries, nomenclature

I am using `nomencl` along with `glossaries`. But I am getting either one of them in the output. I want to use `glossaries` for acronyms and `nomencl` for mathematical equations. How can we do that if we want to both of them in our document output? I also want put them in table of contents at a time. I am using

```
pdflatex document makglossaries document pdflatex document
```

to compile the document. The other way using latexmk is not working for me. I wonder why this happens. I am using the MiKTeX distribution and ActivePerl on Windows XP/Vista.

Comment: The same applies to this question as to your other questions: Please include a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that other users can compile to reproduce your problem. And please stop using two periods `..` after sentences, that's just unnecessary editing work.

Comment: `nomencl` needs a special `makeindex` run. `makeindex filename.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o filename.nst`

Answer (score 5):

`makeglossaries` is a perl script and works in combination with the package `glossaries` with related glossary. `nomencl` requires a special `makeindex` run.

```
makeindex filename.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o filename.nls
```

Answer (score 5):

My advice is to get rid of `nomencl` package and use `glossaries` at its full power. I assume that the sense of this question is to have both a *list of equations* and a *glossary* in the document, whatever tool is used.

In fact, with glossaries, one can define as many glossaries as he wants: a simple *glossary*, a *list of acronyms*, a *list of symbols* and so on.

Instead of using the `nomencl` package, you can define a new glossary (I know the name is misleading, but that's how lists of terms are referred to in the package documentation; you can name your list as you prefer) with the following command:

```
\newglossary{equations}{equ}{eqn}{List of Equations}
```

where: `equations` is the type of the glossary entry, in order to distinguish it from an ordinary glossary entry; `equ` and `eqn` are file extensions for auxiliary files; `List of Equations` is the title of your list, as it will be printed in the table of contents and in the text.

To define an entry to be added to this list, use the glossaries command:

```
\newglossaryentry{sml}{type=equations,name={$\nabla B = 0$},description={Second Maxwell's Law}}
```

Note the value assigned to the key: `type=equations`; if you don't specify it, it will be added to the main glossary.

To have the glossaries printed, you have to put `\printglossaries` in your document backmatter/frontmatter, and run `makeglossaries` from command line on your root `.tex` file.